# which component to access action result other than render

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, axios

so i am using react-redux. i am trying to open a modal depending on the result set of an action which is an api call. i can access the action result using `this.props` in render but then if i use a conditional statament and update the state it goes into an inifnite loop. so i want to know how else i can access the resultset of an action from inside a component and update the modal etc.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchServices, checkServiceEditable } from '../../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

const sourceType = {
          0: 'CCP',
          1: 'Remedy'
        };

function enumFormatter(cell, row, enumObject) {
    //console.log(cell);
    //console.log(row);
    //console.log(enumObject);
    //console.log(enumObject[cell]);
    return enumObject[cell];
}

class Services extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.meta = {title:'Services',description:'List Services'}
        this.passMetaBack = this.passMetaBack.bind(this);
        this.options = {
          defaultSortName: 'name',  // default sort column name
          defaultSortOrder: 'asc'  // default sort order
        };
        this.editServices = this.editServices.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

        this.state = {
          show: false
        };
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

    passMetaBack = () => {
        this.props.passMetaBack(this.meta);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this);
        this.props.fetchServices();
        this.passMetaBack()
    }

    editServices (id) {
        this.props.checkServiceEditable(id){
            return function(dispatch){
                console.log(dispatch)
            }
        }
    }

    actionButtons(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
        return (
            <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button bsClass="btn btn-sm btn-default btn_service_view show-popover" href={"/api/user/services/owners/id/"+row.id+"/format/xml"} data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="View Service users"  data-original-title="" title=""><FontAwesome name='eye' /></Button>
                <Button bsClass="btn btn-sm btn-default btn_service_dashboard show-popover" href={"/api/user/service/dashboard/id/"+row.id+"/format/xml"} data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="View Service" data-id={row.id} data-original-title="" title=""><FontAwesome name='address-card-o' /></Button>
                <Button bsClass="btn btn-sm btn-info btn_edit_services show-popover" onClick={() =>this.editServices(row.id)} data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Edit Service" data-id={row.id} data-original-title="" title=""><FontAwesome name='pencil' /></Button>
                <Button bsClass="btn btn-sm btn-default btn_service_comms_matrix show-popover" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="View consolidated matrices" data-id={row.id} data-original-title="" title=""><FontAwesome name='handshake-o' /></Button>
                <Button bsClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove_services show-popover" href="/api/admin/remove/service/id/{row.id}/format/json" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Delete Service" data-original-title="" title=""><FontAwesome name='trash' /></Button>
            </ButtonToolbar>
        )
    }


    renderTable(services){
        return <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ services } options={ this.options } pagination striped hover insertRow search tableHeaderClass='table-vf thead'>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' dataSort={true} >Service / Project / Programme</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='ref' >Ref</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='source' 
                         filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', defaultValue: 'CCP' } }>Source</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='owner' >Owner</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataFormat={this.actionButtons.bind(this)}>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>
    }

    render() {
        let table = '' 
            console.log(this.props);
        if(Object.keys(this.props.services).length > 0){
            table = this.renderTable(this.props.services)
        }

        if(Object.keys(this.props.servicesEditCheck).length > 0){
            if(this.props.servicesEditCheck.header.error){
                $('#myModalError .modal-body').html(this.props.servicesEditCheck.header.message);
                //$('#myModalError').modal('show');

            }else{
                let data = this.props.servicesEditCheck.body.recordset.record[0];
                console.log(data);
                //for(let key in data){
                    //$("#"+key.toLowerCase()).val(data[key]);
                //}               
                //$("#mdl_edit_services").modal('show');
                this.handleShow()
            }
        }

        return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row-fluid">
                        <a className="btn btn-success hidden-print" href="/add_service.php"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add New Service</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row-fluid top-buffer">
                        {table}
                    </div>

                    <form name="frm_edit_services" id="frm_edit_services" method="post" className="form-horizontal">           
                    <Modal id="mdl_edit_services" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title>Update Service/Group</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="" /> 
                            <input type="hidden" id="current_ref" name="current_ref" value="" /> 
                            <input type="hidden" id="current_name" name="current_name" value="" /> 
                            <input type="hidden" id="mode" name="mode" value="update" />
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label col-sm-4" for="ref">Service reference (optional):</label>
                                <div className="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" maxlength="15" value="" className="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label col-sm-4" for="name">Service name:</label>
                                <div className="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="48" value="" className="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                          </Modal.Body>
                          <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button bsType="submit" className="btn btn-success hidden-print"><FontAwesome name='floppy-o' /></Button>
                            <span className="help-block">(Click once, changes can take a few seconds to complete)</span>
                          </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal>
                    </form>
                </div>
          );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return { services: state.services, servicesEditCheck: state.servicesEditCheck };
}

//Anything returned from this function will end up as props
//on the User container
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
     // Whenever getUser is called, the result should be passed
     // to all our reducers
     //return {
         //actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, fetchServices, checkServiceEditable ), dispatch)
     //};
     return bindActionCreators({ fetchServices, checkServiceEditable }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Services);
```

The infinite loops occurs here

```
if(Object.keys(this.props.servicesEditCheck).length > 0){
            if(this.props.servicesEditCheck.header.error){
                $('#myModalError .modal-body').html(this.props.servicesEditCheck.header.message);
                //$('#myModalError').modal('show');

            }else{
                let data = this.props.servicesEditCheck.body.recordset.record[0];
                console.log(data);
                //for(let key in data){
                    //$("#"+key.toLowerCase()).val(data[key]);
                //}               
                //$("#mdl_edit_services").modal('show');
                this.handleShow()
            }
        }
```

everytime it hits `this.handleShow()` it updates state and hits `render` which then hits this same line again.

Comment: did you try changing state in componentDidMount?

Comment: `this.props.checkServiceEditable` is called in `editServices` so how woudl that make sense. it would be empty on init load. `editServices` gets triggered by `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `this.state.show == true` in your `handleShow` function and call `this.setState({ show: true })` only when the `show` isn't already set to `true`. 
This way, you prevent the `state` from being unnecessarily updated and your `render` function from being unnecessarily called.